# Can only connect to master database with JDBC Sql Server

Tags: java, android, azure-sql-database, mssql-jdbc

I just successfully connected my android app with a database running on azure cloud services to run simple queries.

The connection string provided by azure already specifies which database I want to connect to, but when it is trying to execute a select query in that database the table cannot be found because the query is being executed on Master database.

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://{servername}:1433;database=BDassistance;user={username};password={password};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
```

`BDassistance` is the database I want to connect to and run queries, but its tables cannot be found and when running

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

it returns "Master".

What is going on here? Did I forget a parameter in my connection?

Comment: The database name parameter is `databaseName` not `database`.

Comment: Thank you so much that was the solution. Why would azure provide that incorrectly?

Comment: If you have a reference to any incorrect documentation, please let me know and I will get it updated.  Thx

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT Thanks. The incorrect connection string is given by the azure cloud portal when selecting JDBC in the connection strings tabs.

Comment: @HowardMejicanos thanks - I will have the team investigate and get it corrected.  Thank you for your patience and apologies you had a poor experience here.