# Hibernate connection with jdbc URL to Azure SQL for specific database (not master)

Tags: sql-server, azure, hibernate, jdbc

I have Java application with Hibernate + Spring. 
Until now it was  working well with MSSQL/Oracle/PostGres, now i'm trying to set it with "Azure SQL Server".

For some reason, it is trying to connect to master even though I specified databaseName in my jdbc URL.

This is  my connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://{server-name}:1433;databaseName=decision1;user=*******;password=*******;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

An this is the error I get:
The server principal "******" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context. ClientConnectionId:*****

Already reviewed: [Can only connect to master database with JDBC Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070013/can-only-connect-to-master-database-with-jdbc-sql-server) but with no luck.

I can log in successfully with that user via SQL Server Management Studio

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which JDBC version did you use? I think you can try to change the jdbc version and try again. Get the JDBC connection string on Portal should like this `jdbc:sqlserver://servername.database.windows.net:1433;database=Mydatabase;user=ServerAdmin@sqlserverleon;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`.

Comment: thanks

actually just find the issue, somewhere in the code the properties are getting messed up so everything after the first semi-colon is ignored.

this is definitely a bug in our application to be fixed. took me too much time to identify.

thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi Michal, you're welcome. I'm glad to help you and hear that you have found the issue. Next step, just fix the bug in your Application. Do you mind I help you post this answer? Then you can mark it, others can know your issue is solved. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations the issue is solved:

"actually just find the issue, somewhere in the code the properties are getting messed up so everything after the first semi-colon is ignored. this is definitely a bug in our application to be fixed. took me too much time to identify."

Hope this helps.